# Installing downloaded Python modules

Tags: python, modules

How can I move downloaded Python modules to my Python directory?

Comment: Could you tell your Python version? Please not that the Software Center should also have some Python modules.

Answer (score 2):

A manual install should be the last step to take if all else fails.

First look in the Ubuntu software repositories (`Synaptic` is nice for this) if the module is available there. Most (if not al) packages have a `python-` or `python3-` prefix depending on the Python version you use.

If it is not available, try with `pip`. It's not installed by default, do so with `sudo apt-get install python-pip` or `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
Installing packages is as easy as `sudo pip install mypackage` (or `pip3`).

If for some reason the above steps don't work, look for a `setup.py` file inside the package. If there's one, try to install with `sudo python setup.py install`

Should there be no `setup.py` file, you can manually copy the module in your PYTHONPATH. Run this command to see where Python searches: `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"`

Answer (score 1):

you no need to move those modules into python directory. all you need to do is simply install them.

how ?
actually every python module will have a file named as setup.py which can be used for installing that module. so simply in the terminal type as

```
python setup.py install
```

so that you can install it.

for more information about module installation in python you can check [python manual](http://docs.python.org/3.1/install/index.html)